# Сказка "про колобок" или "про колобка"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, одушевленность

Интернет признаёт только первый вариант — как единственно правильный. Но поскольку это *сказка* (а не статья о хлебобулочных изделиях), мне больше импонирует второй вариант.
Основание: персонаж с этим именем — одушевленный.

Answer (score 2):

Становление Колобка произошло не сразу: сначала муки наскребли **на колобок** и испекли **колобок**. Только после этого начались чудеса одушевления. Название не должно раскрывать содержание почти детективного сюжета.

Comment: Произведение называется просто "Колобок". Но речь не о том. Если некто сообщает собеседнику (в устной форме) или читателю (в письменной), что он читал сказку про...

Comment: @Виктор, ...сказку **о колобке**.

Answer (score 1):

Вот что я обнаружил. Мультик называется "СКАЗКА ПРО КОЛОБОК" (все заглавными буквами). В Нацкорпусе и Википедии — "про Колобка". Думаю, если с заглавной, то это имя героя (тогда про Колобка), а если нет, то это изделие из теста (тогда про колобок), а в народной сказке, скорее всего, подразумевалось второе, уже потом произошла трансформация.

Comment: Комментарий - выше.

Answer (score 1):

В полном орфографическом словаре русского языка:
[КОЛОБОК](https://slovar.cc/rus/orfo-rus/836174.html)
колобок, -бка (круглый хлебец; о низеньком полном человеке, о полном ребенке) и **Колобок**, -бка (сказочный персонаж).

В лингвострановедческом словаре:
[КОЛОБОК](https://lingvostranovedcheskiy.academic.ru/243/%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%9A)
Персонаж одноименной русской народной сказки — небольшой круглый хлебец. Этимологически название связано с исконно-русским словом *коло*, то есть «круг».
Сюжет сказки прост: **К**олобок, испеченный старухой из последних запасов муки (…) Колобку удается убежать от всех, кроме лисы, которая оказалась хитрее **К**олобка и съела его.

Интересно, что в текстах самой сказки ***колобок*** всегда пишется со строчной буквы.

*Катится [колобок](http://malchishki-i-devchonki.ru/skazka-kolobok.html) по лесу дальше, а навстречу ему медведь идёт, хворост ломает, кусты к земле гнёт.

Катится [колобок](https://deti-online.com/skazki/russkie-narodnye-skazki/kolobok/), а навстречу ему медведь: «Колобок, колобок! Я тебя съем».

Катится [колобок](https://www.detiam.com/%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA/) по лесу, а навстречу ему медведь идёт.*

Нашелся вариант с прописной буквой, но только в тексте песенки:
*Я [Колобок](http://audioskazki.net/archives/276), Колобок!

Я по коробу скребен,

По сусеку метен,

На сметане мешон...*

Чисто интуитивно своим детям я всегда говорила: **про Колобка** — он ведь сказочно-живой, разговаривает и поет!

*А сейчас мы послушаем сказку **про Колобка*** (В. Дмитриева. Настольная книга будущих родителей); *Я всегда ненавидела сказку **про колобка*** (А. Лонская); *Читал детям сказку **про Колобка** и начал прояснять для себя...*
Cомневаетесь — скажите по-другому: ***о*** колобке.

Answer (score 0):

А может имеет смысл использовать вариант **"Сказка о колобке"** (по аналогии с названиями в стиле *"Сказка о попе и о работнике его Балде"*)?
Тем более, что сама сказка в оригинале называется просто **"Колобок"**, поэтому **"Сказка про колобок"** - такое же отступление от оригинала, как и **"Сказка о колобке"**.

Comment: Не о названии речь, а о том, как упомянуть эту сказку в разговоре.

Comment: @М_Г, в таком случае, **"Сказка о колобке"** - вполне благозвучный вариант, не нарушающий нормы русского языка.

Comment: "Умный в гору не пойдет, умный гору обойдет". Но... В устной речи разницы нет, а на письме Вам все равно придется решать, там прописная или строчная К.

Comment: @М_Г, хитрее всего поступили создатели мультфильма, который Вы упоминали в Вашем ответе, написав все заглавными буквами.